# Ugly lines on a CSS gradient background

Tags: css, gradient, lines

I wanted to create a css gradient for a background of a div.

**HTML**

```
<section id="library">
    <div id="listHeader"></div>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
#library {
width: 600px;
margin: 0 auto;
}

#listHeader {
height: 40px;
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#1A1B1B), to(#191919));
border-top: 1px solid rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.6);
border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
```

This gives me the actual gradient I wanted to achieve, but it has some ugly lines all over.

[This is the result I get. (Chrome 11, Mac OSX 10.6.7)](http://cl.ly/6bll)

This also happens with other gradients. 
e.g.

```
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#1D1D1D), to(#181818));
```

Comment: everything is so dark i can't see anything other than the bg and the black box from that link.

Comment: I suggest putting your example up on jsfiddle.net The background of your above example is to dark and distracting.

Comment: @Dan Well, here it is on jsfiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/btqdz/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is called 'banding' and it varies from monitor to monitor. Its not that bad on mine however I also think its because your color range is small for the dimensions of the area you want to fill. Try increasing the color range and play with the dimensions of the box to see the result.

Comment: Great answer, thanks. The only problem is that I can't really change much about the dimensions and the color range so I must find another solution.